# Rails Active storage Unable to autoload constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, aws-sdk-ruby

I've updated rails from 5.1.4 to 5.2 and remove Papaerclip to use Active Storage. I'm using digitalocean spaces. In my development env I've setted credentials in `storage.yml` to save images to digitalocean.

I've added **aws-sdk-s3** gem in gemfile (without version, may be this the problem?).

I run `db:migrate` for active storage.

But when I'm going to submit the form with an image upload html tag, i receive this error:

> Unable to autoload constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you run `rails active_storage:install` to copy over active_storage migrations?

Comment: @iGian yes, i've run rails active_storage:install

Answer (score 2):

Did you install MiniMagic Gem

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Analyzer/ImageAnalyzer.html

Comment: This was my issue. I upgraded to Rails 6.0, and wanted to use Vips for image processing, however Active Storage still requires MiniMagik for Image Analysis. Jesus I hate Active Storage.

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating from an older version of Rails to a version that contains ActiveStorage, it is important to create the boiler plate storage.yml. You may have stored your credentials through

```
rails credentials:edit
```

And your setup for S3 might look similar to this:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key] %>
  region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:region] %>
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket] %>
```

The issue that I had was that when I saved my credentials on storage.yml, all of the keys were saved as comments. Run `EDITOR='atom --wait' rails credentials:edit` (with the editor that you are using; in this example, I am using atom) and make sure that none of your items are commented through #'s. When you close the window, your credentials should automatically be saved and can be accessed.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, I ran into the same error. 
Only to find out hour later, that the issue was in my `storage.yaml` file

There was an error in the logs 
`Psych::SyntaxError - (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1:`

which meant that `Psych` which is a `YAML` parser was having an issue with parsing the file.

It was throwing the `Unable to autoload constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable` Error because of a **Spacing issue**

Hope this helps anyone out there

**EXAMPLE BEFORE**

```
| amazon:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id] %>
    secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key] %>
    region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:region] %>
    bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket] %>
```

**EXAMPLE AFTER**

```
|amazon:
   service: S3
   access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id] %>
   secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key] %>
   region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:region] %>
   bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket] %>
```